# Coreplot installation

Tags: ipad

I installed Coreplot But not working properly

I followed the steps below

1. Download Coreplot 9.0
2. Copy the Downloaded folder and paste in to the Application folder with name CorePlotFramework
3. Add libCorePlot Cocoatouch.a in to the Xcode
4. Add QuartzCore frame work
5. Drag and paste the libCorePlot Cocoatouch.a in to Link Libraries with Binaries

Edit Project settings
  Other Linker Flags -->-lxml2 -ObjC 
  Header Search Paths -->CorePlotFramework

Now it's not working.

Comment: What's not working? What are the symptoms? What have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

- Open your apps Target Build Settings, and for Other Linker Flags include this: **-ObjC** and **-all_load**
- Change your C/C++ Compiler in the project build settings to LLVM GCC 4.2 or LLVM 1.6.